# Making a simple timeline with moment JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Im trying to create a simple report where I get entries from an ajax request and I want to simply group my entries by the day of the week. For example I want to come out something simple as:

```
-----------------------------------
Monday - May 2nd - 2016
-----------------------------------
Entry 1 
Description
Date: 2016-05-02 09:45
-----------------------------------
Entry 2 
Description
Date: 2016-05-02 10:55
-----------------------------------

-----------------------------------
Tuesday - May 3rd - 2016
-----------------------------------
Entry 3
Description
Date: 2016-05-03 11:55
-----------------------------------
Entry 4
Description
Date: 2016-05-03 13:55
-----------------------------------

-----------------------------------
Wednesday - May 4th - 2016
-----------------------------------
No entries to report ....
-----------------------------------

etc ...
```

Here is a jsfiddle of what I got going so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/vLdn68ko/

I know you can get the day of the week with Moment JS `moment().format('dddd');` but what im having issues with is how to get the logic working so that it groups by the day of the week? Not quite sure how to get start with that. Anyone have any idea?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
$.ajax({url:"/SomeUrlBeginninWithSlash",
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {

                    $.each(data.d.results, function (index, incident) {

                                    $('body').append(
                  "<table border='1'>"+
                                        "<TR><TD>Entry ID is"+incident.ID+"</TD></TR>"+
                    "<TR><TD>Description: "+incident.Description+"</TD></TR>"+
                    "<TR><TD>Date: "+incident.Date+"</TD></TR>"+
                                    "</table>"+
                  "<br><br>"

                  );

                                })
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can index the items by date using an object

```
var items_by_date  = {}; // declare an object that will have date indexes

data.d.results.map(function(item){
    var item_date = moment(item.Date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    // if the date index does not exist we need to create it
    if(!items_by_date[item_date]) items_by_date[item_date] = [item];
    // else we can just push the item on that array
    else items_by_date[item_date].push(item);
})

console.log(items_by_date);
  // now you can render how ever you need to
```

https://jsfiddle.net/stevenkaspar/vLdn68ko/2/

Comment: Thanks alot Steven, thats what I needed :). Just a small question, how would you return the data in an organized HTML table tough?

Comment: You don't really want to be passing around HTML strings. It is better to pass objects in variables and then render the data. This makes it much easier to change how that data is rendered and also lets you apply more functions or whatever should you want to alter your data another step and then just pass it to the draw/render data function again